# download HTML file without the JS file in its script tag

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types, content-type

I want download a .html file, so I employ content-type: "text/html". The html file uses some .js file in its script tag, so it downloads both of the files(.html and .js). Is there anyway to download only .html file?

Comment: just go and remove that js content from file

Comment: I didn't write them.I just want to download many html files. For better speed I want to avoid downloading .js files(I actually don't need .js files)

Comment: Take a look at this...I think this is what your aiming for. http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/qt/html_dwnld_tag.htm

Comment: @zazvorniki:thanks for your help, but I didn't find anything related to my problem,which part do you mean?

Comment: Your are trying to allow users to download HTML files correct? That artical gives a few links at the bottom on how to accomplish it. Here's one solution http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/ht/download_link.htm

Comment: I write a javascript file to download many .html files via content-type:"text/html" and I can do it but I want to avoid downloading .js file that it had placed in script tag in .html file

Comment: It is not entirely clear what is your use case. How is the download performed? HTML is just markup. If you get the `.html` file using AJAX, there is no reason for the `.js` file to be downloaded. Can you provide an example or elaborate some more?